# Application Shortcut To Launch On System Boot

Tags: scripting

I have a ts3.desktop file in my /usr/share/applications folder that I want to run on system boot. How this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Type `crontab -e` to edit your crontab file and then add `@reboot gtk-launch ts3 /usr/share/applications` and then save it...

## Breakdown

Essentially this means that *every time you reboot run the* ***.desktop*** *file* ***ts3*** *from folder* ***/usr/share/applications***

## More Information

There are some other ways of doing this, but they are more complicated and are distro-dependent... Even this way(the most simple way) may not work depending on what distro and even what version you have installed... For a more complete version of how to run a **.desktop** file in the command line, look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal) page on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/). For a more in depth explanation of *crontab*, go to [this page](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/crontab.htm).

 
Hope this is useful,
Interesting...

#### Update

The `crontab` file is stored in different locations for every distro... For Ubuntu, the `crontab` file is stored in the following directories:
1) /etc/cron.d/
2) /etc/cron.daily/
3) /etc/cron.hourly/
4) /etc/cron.monthly/
5) /etc/cron.weekly/
**DO NOT UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCES DELETE ANY FILES IN THESE DIRECTORIES**
Only experienced people should mess around with the `cron` directories... For all-intensive purposes, use `crontab -e` to edit your `crontab`.

Comment: Where is the contrab file?

Comment: @johnsmith I posted an update(and warning) about where your `crontab` is, but stick with `crontab -e`.

Comment: Hi, I did as you said, and it doesn't work. When I reboot the ts3 file is not run. I also checked the file again using crontab -e and I do not see the information I put into the file after I saved it.

Comment: It depends on your distro, and you have to save your `crontab`...

Comment: Also: Can you run your .desktop file from the command line in the first place?

Comment: Yes it executes perfectly.

Comment: Then save that command to a script and in your crontab edit `@reboot /path/to/script`

Comment: Yes I also tried doing that using @reboot /usr/bin/teamspeak3-server_linux-amd64/ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh